# Unable to pass image uri in Dsphotoeditor sdk

Tags: android, image, sqlite, sdk, uri

### Image.java class

```
package com.example.memelogy;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Base64;


public class Image {

    private byte[] image;

    public Image(byte[] image) {

        this.image = image;

    }


    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

### DatabaseHandler

```
package com.example.memelogy;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    Context context;
    private static String DATABASE_NAME="memedb.db";
    private static int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    private static String createTableeQuery="create table imageInfo(category TEXT" +",image BLOB)";
    private ByteArrayOutputStream objectByteArrayOutputStream;
    private byte[] imageInBytes;
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try{
            db.execSQL((createTableeQuery));
            Toast.makeText(context, "Table created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void storeImage(ModelClass objectModelClass)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteDatabase objectSqliteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
            Bitmap imageToStoreBitmap=objectModelClass.getImage();
            objectByteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageToStoreBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,objectByteArrayOutputStream);
            imageInBytes=objectByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            ContentValues objectContentValues=new ContentValues();
            objectContentValues.put("category",objectModelClass.getImageCate());
            objectContentValues.put("image",imageInBytes);
            long checkIfQueryRuns= objectSqliteDatabase.insert("imageInfo",null,objectContentValues);
            if (checkIfQueryRuns!=0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Data added into table", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                objectSqliteDatabase.close();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    /*public ArrayList<ModelClass> getAllImagesData(String sql)
    {
        try
        {
            SQLiteDatabase objectSqliteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
            ArrayList<ModelClass> objectModelClassList=new ArrayList<>();
            Cursor  objectCursor=objectSqliteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from imageInfo",null);
            if(objectCursor.getCount()!=0)
            {
                while(objectCursor.moveToNext())
                {
                    String nameOfImage=objectCursor.getString(0);
                    byte[] imageBytes=objectCursor.getBlob(1);
                    Bitmap objectBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes,0,imageBytes.length);
                    objectModelClassList.add(new ModelClass(nameOfImage,objectBitmap));
                }
                return objectModelClassList;
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "No values in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }*/
    public Cursor getAllImagesData(String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(query, null);
    }

}
```

### ImageListAdapter

```
package com.example.memelogy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private  int layout;
    private ArrayList<Image> imageList;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Image> imageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public Image getImage(int position) {
        return imageList.get(position);
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtName, txtPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        if(row == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

           // holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
          //  holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        Image image = imageList.get(position);

        //holder.txtName.setText(image.getName());
       // holder.txtPrice.setText(image.get());

        byte[] memeImage = image.getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(memeImage, 0, memeImage.length);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return row;
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.memelogy;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView logo;
TextView sad;
TextView funny;
TextView cinema;
TextView politics;
TextView sports;
TextView nostalgia;
TextView wholesome;
TextView memoLogyText;
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Image> list;
    ImageListAdapter adapter = null;
private DatabaseHandler objectDatabaseHandler;
//private RecyclerView objectRecyclerView;
//private RVAdapter objectRvAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        logo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
objectDatabaseHandler=new DatabaseHandler(this);

        sad=findViewById(R.id.sad);
        funny=findViewById(R.id.funny);
        cinema=findViewById(R.id.cinema);
        politics=findViewById(R.id.politics);
        sports=findViewById(R.id.sport);
        nostalgia=findViewById(R.id.nostalgia);
        wholesome=findViewById(R.id.wholesome);

        memoLogyText=findViewById(R.id.memelogytext);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ImageListAdapter(this, R.layout.single_row, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);



        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Funny'");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
            list.add(new Image(image));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



        funny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Funny'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        cinema.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Cinema'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        politics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Politics'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        wholesome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Wholesome'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        sports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Sports'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        sad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Sad'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        nostalgia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = objectDatabaseHandler.getAllImagesData("SELECT image FROM imageInfo where category='Nostalgia'");
                list.clear();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("image"));
                    list.add(new Image(image));
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });




        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                CharSequence[] items = {"Edit", "Cancel"};
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            // Edit

                            Image image = adapter.getImage(position);
                            byte[] inputImageUri = image.getImage();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DsPhotoEditorActivity.class);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(inputImageUri.toString()));
                            startActivity(intent);

                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            switch (requestCode) {

                case 200:

                    Uri outputUri = data.getData();

                    // handle the result uri as you want, such as display it in an imageView;

                    // imageView.setImageURI(outputUri);

                    break;

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

I'm trying to send image uri to other activity (using DsPhotoEditor sdk, so can not change its activity code), I have coded watching a YT video that guides how to store image and show in Gridview. I successfully retrieved image in my own created activity called editimage.java which shows and provide menu to edit image. image. In main activity images are showed in Gridview and when I long press on particular image it shows alert dialog box which has two options edit and cancel when I click on edit it sends image to editimage activity (successfully working). Due to time limitation I am unable to code for image filters ,putting stickes and text on image. so I am using sdk(DsPhotoEditor) which provides features that I want to implement in my app. when I select edit from dialog box as I described previously , but shows exceptions as below. sdk activity only accept imageuri which I do not know how to do in my code. Please help as to solve:

```
23-05-07 11:04:33.380 1909-1909/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.memelogy, PID: 1909
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.memelogy/com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.activity.DsPhotoEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int[] android.os.Bundle.getIntArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int[] android.os.Bundle.getIntArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at a.a.b.b.c.onCreateView(Unknown Source:44)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2505)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1303)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2431)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2210)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2166)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2067)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3057)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3004)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:185)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8599)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
```